# Fourier series converging to a function which doesn't satisfy Dirichlet's conditions

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, periodic-functions

[Fourier series of](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/step-by-step/fourier%20x%5E%7B2%7D%2C%20%20%5Cleft%5B-%5Cpi%2C%20%20%5Cpi%5Cright%5D?or=input) $x^2$ over $[-\pi,\ \pi]$ is $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{4 \left(-1\right)^{n} \cos{\left(n x \right)}}{n^{2}} + \frac{\pi^{2}}{3}
$$

[Graphing the two functions](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=graph%20Divide%5BPower%5Bpi%2C2%5D%2C3%5D%2BSum%5B%5C%2840%294Power%5B%5C%2840%29-1%5C%2841%29%2Cn%5DDivide%5Bcos%5C%2840%29nx%5C%2841%29%2CPower%5Bn%2C2%5D%5D%5C%2841%29%2C%7Bn%2C1%2Cinfinity%7D%5D%20and%20Power%5Bx%2C2%5D) we can see them coinciding, apparently over $[-\pi,\ \pi]$.

[image: graph]

But the function $x^2$ doesn't satisfy one of Dirichlet's conditions of being periodic and hence its Fourier series should not coverage to it. So how is the series converging to the function?

Comment: (It's Dirichlet, not Dirchilet.)

Comment: It converges to the limit which is periodic function of course. The limit is $x^2$ on $[-\pi, \pi]$ but then you have to "make" it periodic by shifting it to the right and left. Say, on $[\pi,3\pi]$ it is gonna be $(x-2\pi)^2$.